# Rename the multiple files while moving them to different directory with dynamic file names in unix

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I want to rename the dynamic files while moving them to a different directory. 
File name are:

```
File_{Date}_1
File_{Date}_2
File_{Date}_3
File_{Date}_4
```

New file names should be:

```
File_{Date}_1.txt
File_{Date}_2.txt
File_{Date}_3.txt
File_{Date}_4.txt
```

I tried to use the mv command but seems that can't move the multiple files. 
The number of files is not fixed so I can't move each file line by line. 
Please help to suggest.

Comment: You should probably narrow down your question after browsing some of the [other similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rename+%5Bbash%5D+is%3Aq).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to get away only using the find commands helpful `-exec`.

`find /path/to/files/ -type f -exec mv {} /new/destination/ +`

`-exec` Will replace the `{}` with the name of the files.  The trick is at the end you terminate the `-exec` command with a `+` instead of a `\;`.  This tells find that it should wait to execute the command until it has expanded the `{}` to, i believe, the kernels limit on arguments.

Basically it will do `mv f1 f2 f3 f4 f5... fN /new/destination/`

Obviously though this doesn't rename the files. So to finish up I would run

`cd /new/destination/; find ./ -type f -exec mv {} {}".txt" \;`

If you can work out of the directory that holds your file by `cd`'ing into it before you run the command then you can get away with a single find command.

`cd /path/to/files; find ./ -type f -printf "%P\n" -exec {} c/{}.txt \;`

Unfortunately you can't use two `{}` with a `+` ending with find but still the single command should run faster.  Hope this gives you some options.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop and use `mv` command on each of the files or use the `rename` command:

```
rename 's/$/.txt/' File_*
```

(alter the glob expression depending on how your files are named).

Comment: I get this error when I use the rename command 
bash: rename: command not found

Comment: That means you don't have it installed on your system. You can instead use a simple for loop and mv as well.

Comment: Assuming files are in the current directory (otherwise alter the loop with the path):
`for file in File_*; do
  mv "${file}" "{file}.txt" || { echo "error moving $file"; exit 1; }
done`

Comment: the above command is creating just one file from four as {file}.txt & mv: 0653-401 Cannot rename File* to File*.txt:
             A file or directory in the path name does not exist.
error moving File*